# innerHTML not working in any browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>css demo</title>
</head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
    (function(){
        var html = '<p>';
            html += 'Hello World';
            html += '</p>';

        $(document.body).innerHTML = html;  
        //document.body.innerHTML = html;
    })
</script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

$(document.body).innerHTML = html; // jQuery one is not working either.
document.body.innerHTML = html; // normal JS trying to query DOM is not working either.

What's the actually issue here?. I know while using jQuery we don't need to use innerHTML to append the HTML thing, just was trying and learning it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to get the dom element, `$(document.body)` returns a jQuery wrapped element which does not have `innerHTML` property

```
$(document.body).get(0).innerHTML = html;
```

or simple

```
document.body.innerHTML = html;
```

using jQuery

```
$('body').html(html)
```

also it looks like the anonymous function is not called

```
(function(){
    var html = '<p>';
    html += 'Hello World';
    html += '</p>';

    document.body.innerHTML = html;
})()
```

if you need to wait for dom ready then

```
jQuery(function($){
    var html = '<p>';
    html += 'Hello World';
    html += '</p>';

    $('body').html(html)
})
```

Answer (score 2):

As simple as you can do with `html()` is

```
  $('body').html(html);
```

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fRUUd/1499/)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`$.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function of jQuery :

> This method **uses the browser's innerHTML property**. Some browsers may
>   not return HTML that exactly replicates the HTML source in an original
>   document. For example, Internet Explorer sometimes leaves off the
>   quotes around attribute values if they contain only alphanumeric
>   characters.

```
var html = '<p>';
html += 'Hello World';
html += '</p>';

$(document.body).html(html);
```

Living example: http://jsfiddle.net/YTaRG/

Answer (score 1):

```
 (function(){
        var html = '<p>';
            html += 'Hello World';
            html += '</p>';

        $("body").html(html);  
        //document.body.innerHTML = html;
    })
```

Comment: You need to execute that function.

Answer (score 1):

actually the browser run your script before  loaded. you have to setup a timer or add onDomReady event

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jQuery, you can also do this the jQuery way:

```
$(function(){
    var html = '<p>';
            html += 'Hello World';
            html += '</p>';

        $('body').html(html);  

});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k4psh/)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot one thing:

```
(function(){
});
```

This will not run, you should do:

```
$(function() {       
   //...
   //and then...
   $('body').html(html);
});
```

When you're using jQuery to select an element, jQuery adds an array wrapper for it so if you want to use both the jquery selector and the native JavaScript html you should do it like:

```
$(document.body)[0].innerHTML = html;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do like this

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     var html = '<p>';
        html += 'Hello World';
        html += '</p>';

     $('body').html(html);  
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

change `$(document.body).innerHTML = html;` to `$(document.body).html(html);` which is a right way to do it using jQuery.

or

change `$(document.body).innerHTML = html;` to `$(document.body)[0].innerHTML = html;` if you dont want to use `html()` method.

Answer (score 0):

That self-executing function isn't quite right, you need to change the last line to:

```
})();
```

But even once you fix that, because the script is before the opening body tag, it's running before the body has been constructed in the DOM. If you watch the console, you'll see an exception like "Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null". Moving the script into the body will fix this.

So here's the native JS version:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>css demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        (function(){
            var html = '<p>';
                html += 'Hello World';
                html += '</p>';
            document.body.innerHTML = html;
        })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And then here is a jQuery version:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>css demo</title>
</head>
<body>
            <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        (function(){
            var html = '<p>';
                html += 'Hello World';
                html += '</p>';
            $('body').html(html);
        })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```